# How to get an EntityFramework Migration to run different SQL for different database providers

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've an Entity Framework 6 application. I'm migrating it from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. One of the migrations looks like this:

using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

```
public partial class SetIsActiveToTrue : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql(@"UPDATE dbo.""AspNetUsers"" SET ""IsActive"" = 1;");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

}

This works fine on SQL server, but fails on PostgreSQL because the IsActive column is a Boolean and expects True/False instead of 1/0. Is there a way to get the migration to run different SQL for each DB?

I have looked at all the base class items and they none of them seem to give the provider type. The Up and Down methods don't take any parameters with this information either.

Comment: Maybe instantiate a context, then check `context.Database.Connection.ConnectString`?